# How to remove a menu item from Gedit from a plugin

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, menuitem, gedit

I developed a plugin to replace some functionality in Gedit. This functionality is presented through one menu item.

How could I remove the current menu item to add a identical new one, except that this new menu item will be bound to my callback?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it on existing applications, but in general it boils down to the following steps.

1. Get the `UIManager`: `GObject.property(type=Gedit.Window).get_ui_manager()`.
2. Acquire the current UI definition using [`UIManager.get_ui`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkuimanager.html#method-gtkuimanager--get-ui). Use this to determine which item to remove.
3. Retrieve the item using [`Builder.get_object`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbuilder.html#method-gtkbuilder--get-object) using the name found in the UI definition.
4. I'm not sure for menu's, but on the retrieved item you can now probably simply call [`destroy`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkobject.html#method-gtkobject--destroy). Alternatively, you might get the main menu item and remove the child you want with the [`get_children`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcontainer.html#method-gtkcontainer--get-children) method (i.e. `for i in menu.get_children(): menu.remove(i)`, where `i` is the child you want to get rid of: you'll probably have to inspect it to know which one to remove.
5. Finally, explicitly refresh the UI with [`UIManager.ensure_update`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkuimanager.html#method-gtkuimanager--ensure-update).

As said, I didn't try it, nor do I have a Linux installation nearby to verify this on, but I hope this gives you enough pointers to reach a solution.